# setOnSelectedListener doesn't work on gridView

Tags: android, android-activity, gridview, onclick, onitemselectedlistener

I looked for some answers about onItemSelected but all I found was that they needed to use onItemClick.

In my application, i want that the user will select his name that displays on the gridView, then Click enter, and appears the alertDialog for entering his password.

Tried something but it didn't work for me, here is the relevant code:

```
waiterList = new ArrayList<Waiter>();

    waiterList = dataBaseHelper.showWaiters();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, waiterList);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            waiter = waiterList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

And the function that calls the click on the button:

```
public void Enter(View view) {

        if (gridView.isSelected()){

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password_dialog, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder passwordDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            passwordDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.get_id_uniq));
            passwordDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.enter_id));

            passwordDialog.setView(dialogLayout);

            passwordDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.next), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    password = input.getText().toString();
                    if (password.equals(waiter.getPass())) {

                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Zone.class));


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Wrong pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            });

            passwordDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = passwordDialog.show();
            input = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);


            }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Waiter isnt selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove gridView.isSelected(). This will return you view state.